# Cannot assign to property 'observationTime' is a get-only property

Tags: ios, swift, object, getter-setter

I am getting this error when trying to set the observationTime to a time interval. Not sure why I can set a property, ive set it like this in other places

```
weatherReading?.observationTime = NSTimeIntervalSince1970

@objcMembers class WeatherThirdPartyReadings: NSObject  {

    private var _temperature: Double
    private var _speed: Double
    private var _direction: Double
    private var _observationTime: Double
    private var _isSummaryLoaded: Bool

    var temperature: Double {
        return _temperature
    }
    var speed: Double {
        return _speed
    }
    var direction: Double {
        return _direction
    }
    var observationTime: Double {
        return _observationTime
    }
    var isSummaryLoaded: Bool {
        return _isSummaryLoaded
    }

    init(temperature: Double, speed: Double, direction: Double, observationTime: Double, isSummaryLoaded: Bool) {
        self._temperature = temperature
        self._speed = speed
        self._direction = direction
        self._observationTime = observationTime
        self._isSummaryLoaded = isSummaryLoaded
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating backing `_` properties at all? This looks like it should be be properties (`var temperature: Double` and nothing else).

Comment: To add to the previous comment by @RobNapier, if desired, you can make the properties writable only by the class by making the setter private. For example. `private(set) var observationTime: Double`.

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
var observationTime: Double { 
    set { 
        _observationTime = newValue
    }
    get{ 
        return _observationTime
    }
}
```

As this

```
var observationTime: Double {
    return _observationTime
}
```

makes it a read only property which the3 default implementation of `get`

---

```
@objcMembers class WeatherThirdPartyReadings: NSObject  {

    var temperature: Double
    var speed: Double
    var direction: Double
    var observationTime: Double
    var isSummaryLoaded: Bool

    init(temperature: Double, speed: Double, direction: Double, observationTime: Double, isSummaryLoaded: Bool) {
        self.temperature = temperature
        self.speed = speed
        self.direction = direction
        self.observationTime = observationTime
        self.isSummaryLoaded = isSummaryLoaded
    }
}
```

Comment: is that something you need when working with swift and objective c in the project? becuase ive never had to do that with just swift

Comment: no you don't have to use objective-c `_`  structure you can use what in edit and that if you can omit `private`

Comment: The first half of this answer is giving bad advice. Get rid of `_observationTime` completely. Then make `observationTime` properly without the needless backing variable.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you use this syntax you are saying the public property only has a getter and no setter is available. You need to also create the setter for the property.

```
var observationTime: Double {
    get {
        return _observationTime
    }
    set {
        _observationTime = newValue
    }
}
```

Unless you explicitly need a backing variable for some other reason not indicated in your post, you could simply just declare the variable like so:

```
var observationTime: Double
```

Comment: There is no reason for this in Swift. Get rid of `_observationTime` and then just have `var observationTime: Double`. If you want the setter to be private, then say so: `private(set) var observationTime: Double`.

Comment: @rmaddy OP asked about fixing their error. There is no reason to use a backing variable in this simple example, there is however, many use cases for them.